# Journey Builder Question> Do Contacts who have aged-out of a Journey count towards the goal?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, goals

When looking at Journey Builder Goals... Does Journey Builder evaluate contacts who have exited / aged out ? or only contacts who are "in" the journey?

My use case is to get customer to submit an application, my journey is only 5 days. I am trying to understand if a person who applies on day 6, 7, 8, etc. is counted our not.  Documentation is not clear.

Thank you

Comment: Follow up Question - It looks like Journey Data is not available in JB Goals. So in my same use case - if a customer can submit mutliple application - is it possible to set my goals to look at the application that triggered the customer to enter the journey?

Answer (score 1):

[JB Goals](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_goals.htm&type=5) are evaluated:

- at the end of each wait activity.
- each contact is evaluated every 24 hours

if the contact is not in the journey it would not go through the process to be evaluated against goals.